# npm build prod doesn't load app.css file (it is empty)

Tags: reactjs, laravel, production

I have Laravel project with React and Inertia in there.
When I run `npm build dev`, everything works fine.

When I run `npm build prod`, I see that there are problems with css.
Navigating to Sources, I see that app.css file is empty.

This is my first project I am building like this. It was created by another developer. Can you, please, point me out where to look at? I also add structure of my folders, not sure which file should I modify to fix that.

**No css inside the file, just header**
[image: app.css is empty]

My `webpax.mix.js` file is like this:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const path = require('path');

mix
    .js('resources/js/public.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .react()
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('tailwindcss'),
        require('autoprefixer'),
    ])
    .webpackConfig({
        output: { chunkFilename: 'js/[name].js?id=[chunkhash]' },
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                '@': path.resolve('resources/js')
            }
        },
    })
    .version()
    .sourceMaps();
```

**My project structure**

[image: file structure]

Comment: Could you share your `webpack.mix.js` file contents?

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa I have updated my question, adding file contents